# Does DispatchSemaphore wait for specific thread objects?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I implemented a semaphore today and it raised some questions about semaphores, threads, and queues. Are my following notations accurate?

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial")

someAsyncMethod {

    serialQueue.async {

        // When someAsyncMethod returns, this queue, behind the scenes,
        // creates a Thread/NSThread object and approaches the
        // semaphore and it is this thread object that decrements
        // the semaphore counter.

        // The next time someAsyncMethod returns, a new thread object
        // is created behind the scenes (by the queue) and this thread
        // object is made to wait until something (anything) signals
        // it is done.

        semaphore.wait()

        // do work...
        someMethod()

    }

}

func someMethod() {

    // do work...

    // This task may ultimately be on a different thread than
    // where it started despite being in the same queue
    // (since not every task is guaranteed to run on the same thread)
    // but it doesn't matter, any object can signal the semaphore.

    semaphore.signal()

}
```

1. Do semaphores respond to specific thread objects/instances?
2. Is a new thread object/instance created every time `someAsyncMethod` returns and enters the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s tackle these one at a time:

> ```
> someAsyncMethod {
>
>     serialQueue.async {
>
>         // When someAsyncMethod returns, this queue, behind the scenes,
>         // creates a Thread/NSThread object and approaches the
>         // semaphore and it is this thread object that decrements
>         // the semaphore counter.
>
>         // The next time someAsyncMethod returns, a new thread object
>         // is created behind the scenes (by the queue) and this thread
>         // object is made to wait until something (anything) signals
>         // it is done.
>
>         semaphore.wait()
>
>         // do work...
>         someMethod()
>     }
> }
> ```

First, a minor detail, but `async` doesn’t “create” threads. GCD has a pool of worker threads, and `async` just grabs one of these idle worker threads. (It’s why GCD is performant, as it avoids creating/destroying threads all the time, which is a costly exercise. It draws upon its pool of worker threads.)

The second time you call `async` on the same serial queue, you might get the same thread the next time. Or you might get a different worker thread from the pool. You have no assurances either way. Your only assurance is that the queue is serial (because you defined
it as such).

But, yes, if the semaphore started with a count of 1, the first time it would just decrement the counter and carry on. And, yes, if that semaphore hadn’t yet been signaled by the time you got to that second `wait`, yes it would wait for a `signal`.

But the idea of using this non-zero dispatch semaphore in conjunction with a serial queue seems highly suspect. Usually you use serial queues to coordinate different tasks, or, in rare cases, use semaphores, but almost never both at the same time. Generally, the presence of semaphores, at all, is concerning, because there are almost always better solutions available.

You then had:

> ```
> func someMethod() {
>
>     // do work...
>
>     // This task may ultimately be on a different thread than
>     // where it started despite being in the same queue
>     // (since not every task is guaranteed to run on the same thread)
>     // but it doesn't matter, any object can signal the semaphore.
>
>     semaphore.signal()
>
> }
> ```

This code, because it was called from inside the previous code block’s `serialQueue.async`, will absolutely still be running on the same thread from which you called `someMethod`.

So, therefore, this code doesn’t quite make sense. You would never `signal` from the same thread that would call `wait` on the same thread. The whole point of semaphores is that one thread can `wait` for a signal from a *different* thread.

E.g. it might make sense if, for example, `someMethod` was doing something equivalent to:

```
func someMethod() {
    someOtherQueue.async {
        // do work...

        // Because this is dispatched to a different queue and we know is
        // now running on a different thread, now the semaphore has some 
        // utility, because it only works if it’s a different thread than
        // where we’ll later call `wait`...

        semaphore.signal()
    }
}
```

Now, all of this begs the question about the purpose of the serial queue in conjunction with this semaphore. I’m afraid that in the attempt to abstract this away from the unrelated details of your code base, you’ve made this a bit too abstract. So it’s hard to advise you on a better pattern without understanding the broader problem this code was attempting to solve.

But, with no offense intended, there almost certainly are going to be much better approaches. We can’t just can’t advise on the basis of the information provided thus far.

---

You concluded with two questions:

> 1. Do semaphores respond to specific thread objects/instances?

Nope. It’s for one thread to signal to another, different, thread. But there are no other constraints other than that.

> 2. Is a new thread object/instance created every time someAsyncMethod returns and enters the queue?

As I hope I’ve made clear above, the closure dispatched to serial queue with `async` may end up on the same worker thread or may end up on another worker thread.

But that’s not the real concern here. The real concern is that the `wait` and `signal` calls are made from separate threads, not whether subsequent `wait` calls are.

Comment: The problem I was trying to solve was this: a database method was returning results in rapid succession and I placed this return into a serial queue (which was fine). However, this method (to parse these results) evolved into something more complex and I had to make async requests within a loop within this method before I could call complete. Therefore, I used a dispatch group (`enter` on each iteration, `leave` when the async returned (success or failure)). The problem I had was that when it was time to call `dispatch.notify(queue:execute:)`, I had to select a queue to finish the job...

Comment: ...and I selected the serial queue. The problem was that by the time it reached this point, the database had returned a new set of results and was next in line in the serial queue. I assumed that `notify` was next in line before anything else got into the queue but that wasn't the case. This caused the return method to be interleaved with itself. I thought to create an additional serial queue and nest them but I ended up using a global (concurrent) queue to handle the method with a semaphore and it works as expected.

Comment: @hgale - If you want to notify that the loop of async tasks are done, we’d probably not `notify()` on the database queue, but rather on the main queue, so that you can update the UI with the successful completion. The [Concurrency Programming with GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=498), about 8:18 into the video, offers nice ways to think about how to structure complicated apps. Whether you need all those queues is unclear, but just a thought. But I’d strive to excise the semaphore. It’s inefficient to block threads and It introduces deadlock risks.

Comment: But what if I don't want to notify onto the main because there is another async task that follows? The semaphore does such an effective job at telling the database return to wait until the last pass has completed (however it meanders through other queues). Is this pattern really something to be avoided?

Comment: First, yes, the semaphore pattern is really to be avoided. (If we needed to manage dependencies between async tasks, we might use custom asynchronous `Operation` object subclasses.) Second, do you really need to make subsequent database updates wait for the prior batch’s asynch requests? That’s why I shared that link with separate queues for separate subsystems. If you really need that second batch of database requests to wait for the first batch of asynchronous requests, do what you have to do, but it doesn’t sound right.

Answer (score 0):

Semaphores are not thread-specific. The whole point is to coordinate among threads, so they have to be usable by multiple threads.

In this specific case, there's no need for a semaphore (if those are the only uses) because you're using a serial queue. By definition, a serial queue only allows one of the tasks queued to it to run at a time, in first-in-first-out order. That is, the second task doesn't need to wait on the semaphore to avoid running simultaneously with the first task because it isn't even allowed to start until the first task has completed.

When you put a task on a queue asynchronously, the calling code can continue on immediately. The task is more like a data object being put into a data structure (queue). Grand Central Dispatch uses a pool of threads to pop a task off of a queue and execute it. Whether it has to create a new thread or not depends on whether there are sufficient idle threads in the pool already.

Comment: I understand there isn't a need for a semaphore in this pseudocode; I made the example simple purposely to illustrate my question. And I understand semaphores aren't thread-specific, but that isn't my question. My question is about the creation of threads internally (by the queue) and how semaphores distinguish between the requesters. Every article I've read about the topic uses the terms thread and queue interchangeably when they aren't interchangeable. I think people largely misunderstand (or just ignore) the details of how this works which is what begs my questions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "distinguish between the requesters", but, well, they don't. The example isn't just simple, it means that the semaphore can never be contested. Nothing will ever block on that semaphore, so the behavior of the semaphore is moot.

Comment: Not true, because you don't know what kind of work is performed in these methods and how they're invoked. If there was just one extra async task within the method and the method was called in rapid succession then there would be contention.

Comment: Not if the only uses of the semaphore are the ones shown. If there are other uses then the example is just misleading. In any case, it's very unclear what you're asking that I didn't already explain. For example, you never explained "distinguish between the requesters".

Answer (score 0):

The basics are this:

A *queue* is a tool for managing a collection of tasks.

Every task is executed on a *thread*.

A *semaphore* is way of coordinating tasks, which *might* be running on different threads.

Whether each task creates a new thread, or only some tasks do, or maybe all tasks run on the same thread **is entirely up to Grand Central Dispatch**. GCD relieves you of the burden of worrying about threads. Threads will be created, destroyed, or reused as GCD sees fit according to the capabilities, resources, and load of your system.

Which is just a polite way of saying "stop thinking about threads." Assume each task will run on its own thread in its own time (with the exception of very special queues like `Main`). Whether the thread that a task actually executes on is a new thread or a reused thread, and whether that thread gets destroyed after the task runs or gets reused for another task is the domain of the man behind the curtain.

If you need to coordinate a pool of resources or wait for a set of tasks to complete, that's when you use semaphores and/or any of the queue-based tools like serial queues, dispatch groups, barriers, and so on.

I hope that helps.